# Visual Studio Snippets - Blank Line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I am trying to create a Visual Studio snippet and cannot get it to add basically a blank line. See below for my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">

  <CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Bootstrap Row</Title>
      <Shortcut>brow</Shortcut>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="HTML"><![CDATA[<div class="row">
        $selected$$end$
</div>]]>
       </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
<div class="row">
    CursorHere
</div>
```

What I actually am getting is:

```
<div class="row">
CursorHere</div>
```

Any tips or tricks to get this to do what im trying?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tested your snippet in VS2015. It places `/div>` on next line for me, but also it erases `CursorHere` text! It looks like a something is broken in html snippets.

Comment: cursorHere isnt actually supposed to show up as text just literally place the cursor there which this snippet does just it places </div> where right next to the cursor and ignores that empty line where $end$ is. Its driving me mad! I would like to enter a shortcut click tab and bam start typing the code I want. 

Right now I am having to place a character there like $selected$$end$b 

If I have the b there itll do it like I want but just have to either hit backspace or delete to remove the b and then start typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one thing I have tried and it worked but not sure if there is still not a better way out there!

I added basically a literal to the snippet and just gave it a default of "code" so it works how I wanted and I can just begin typing to overwrite what I actually want there.

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">

  <CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Bootstrap Row</Title>
      <Shortcut>brow</Shortcut>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>classes</ID>
          <ToolTip>Add Addition Classes</ToolTip>
          <Default></Default>
        </Literal>

        <Literal>
          <ID>text</ID>
          <ToolTip></ToolTip>
          <Default>code</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="HTML"><![CDATA[<div class="row $classes$">
                                            $selected$$text$$end$
                                    </div>]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Output:

```
<div class="row ">
    code
</div>
```

Like I said above code is already selected so you can just start typing without having to delete.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Insert `$end$` just before `]]` in `CDATA` block. Full specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets-schema-reference?view=vs-2019#code

By telling VS where it should place the cursor after the snippet is inserted, you prevent the new line and placing the cursor before the inserted code.